# Phone freezes when camera.release() is called

Tags: android, android-camera

Hi I'm trying to get camera functionality to work on my app. The problem is, on one phone in particular - Samsung Galaxy Mini.

After I take a picture using the camera and previews, the phone freezes when I call camera.release(). I have to remove battery to reset it.

This is how I release the camera:

```
try 
{
     mCamera.stopPreview();
     mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
     mCamera.release();
     mCamera = null;
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
     // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
}
```

I am also getting this weird native exception in logcat after the call:

```
03-10 09:45:56.080: E/mm-camera(95): camera_issue_ctrl_cmd: error (Bad address): type 43, length 0, status 40856
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the below open source camera code it will help you

[Open Camera](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencamera/)

and use it on surface destroyed

```
if(flag){
         camera.release();
     camera = null;
     previewing = false;
  }else{
        camera.stopPreview();
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what the 'flag' is please?

Comment: flag here is used to check the condition to stop the activity